# Convert string into binary in Hive

Tags: string, binary, hive, converters

I want to match user ids from two tables in Hive. Unfortunately they are stored in different formats. In one table they are `binary` whereas in the second table they are stored as `string`.
What's the function to convert a `string` into `binary` in HiveQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution is to use the `binary()` function. Another way to reach the same result is to  use the `cast()` function. In this second case the code would look like `cast(userid as binary)`.

Comment: I tried: `insert into dt_binary values (cast ('dev' as binary));` and `insert into dt_binary values (binary('dev'));
` Error : FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values

`

Answer (score 0):

Use the **bin** function.
eg: bin(user_id)

Answer (score -1):

`cast(cast(id as string) as binary) as id`